# Javascript .on("change" only works when change manually [jsFiddle]

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange, google-loader

I have made a jsFiddle with all the data and information about the problem. I think there is easier to understand what's going on:

Please take a look:

http://jsfiddle.net/lukinhasb/GuZq2/

```
$("#estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"]));
```

Mask only changes when you manually select the option. When javascript increments the field with the same data, it doesn't changes the mask.

```
    $("#estado").on("change", function() {
         if ($(this).val() == 'SP') {
             $("#celular_pessoa_fisica").mask("(99) 99999-9999");
                 } else {
             $("#celular_pessoa_fisica").mask("(99) 9999-9999");
             }
```

Comment: Thats the way it should work because when you change via javascript you can also invoke the change listener via java script. There is no key value observing.

Comment: Not 100% on this but i dont think change fires when you manipulate the value via js. You can however manually invoke the event... given your example that would look like: `$("#estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"])).change();`

Comment: Thank you guys for all your replies, it's working with .trigger('change'); !! Have a great day

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how it's intended to work, but you can trigger the change event yourself when you set the value via JS:

```
$("#estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"])).trigger('change');
```

Comment: Solved my problem! Just waiting a few minutes so I can mark your answer

Answer (score 2):

When you change a field with javascript, it wont trigger the change event automatically.  With jQuery, you can trigger change with $elem.change()

Comment: Thank you fiddur, now I'm aware! Have a nice day, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2):

You can trigger a Change on the input so that your function is called:

```
$("#estado").val(unescape(resultadoCEP["uf"])).trigger("change");
```

More information:

1. [jQuery Trigger](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Yes, Thanks a lot for your answer too! have a good time